# Ubuntu 12.04 cannot connect to wireless network (wireless card unspecified)

Tags: wireless, internet

I have just recently installed 12.04 and I can't seem to get it to hook up to my wireless network. I tried plugging it in directly and it worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: We need to find out what wireless card you have. please run the following command - `lspci | grep Network` this should result in a two lines such as this - `03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300` With that information we should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Wireless support can be dependent on your wireless chip.  I would recommend using `lspci` (terminal command) to find your wireless chipset and then google around using that information to see if others have theirs working.  good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah It is just weird cause on Windows it works fine. I've been googling around but I haven't found anything that I either understood or that worked.

Answer (score 0):

A lot.

- Is your Wi-Fi supported by Ubuntu? Not all are.
- Is the device turned on?
- Is the device blocked? Hardware or software alike can block Wi-Fi.
- Drivers work as they should?
- No drivers conflict / shadowing?
- Are you within reach for your Wi-Fi? Some signals can be blocked surprisingly easy.
- Is your router ready to work with new device? Some older models may require restarting to "pick" up new kid on the block.

There is more, so perhaps you could extend the question with information what have you tried so far and how it went?

For starters, when I had WiFi troubles I looked here:
[Ubuntu 10.04 Wireless Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html)

Don't worry that it's for 10.04, identifying devices, commands and other links found there should be a good reference anyway.

More info can be found in [community docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs)

Answer (score 0):

It's supported and on...as I said, it sees the network...every time I click on "additional drivers" it crashes and shows an error report.  The adapter is 18 inches from the modem; shouldn't be a problem. It already sees it.

The adapter finds my home network and a hidden one (which must be a neighbor's), but every time I click on the home network the window remains blank.

Since the driver thing keeps crashing and it won't read the CD, I'm guessing that's the problem, but I'm new to Ubuntu, so I wondered if there might be something else.